# How to use Multiindex to be aggregated into list in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like this :

```
    class1  class2  values  values2
0        1       0       1        5
1        1       1       2        8
2        1       0       3        3
3        2       0       5        6
4        2       0       2        5
5        2       1       4        2
6        2       1       2        3
7        2       1       3        1
8        3       0       1        3
9        3       0       3        3
10       3       1       4        2
11       3       1       2        4
```

I hope to set Multiindex based on `class1` and `class2`, and then aggregate `value` and `value2` into list. So I want to get the **result** should like this:

```
   class1  class2     values    values2
0       1       0     [1, 3]     [5, 3]
1       1       1        [2]        [8]
2       2       0     [5, 2]     [6, 5]
3       2       1  [4, 2, 3]  [2, 3, 1]
4       3       0     [1, 3]     [3, 3]
5       3       1     [4, 2]     [2, 4]
```

I tried it done by:

```
df.groupby(['class1']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
```

It's no problem. But I tried Multiindex by:

```
df.groupby(['class1','class2']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
```

Show error:

> ValueError: Function does not reduce

I also tried it done by:

```
df.groupby(['class1', 'class2'])['values'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()
```

This method can only be handled separately for `value` or `Value2`.

Can anyone help me with a better way? Thanks in advance

Comment: Interestingly I can't replicate your issue, `df.groupby(['class1','class2']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist()).reset_index()` works fine, as does: `df.groupby(['class1','class2']).agg(list).reset_index()` what version of pandas are you running?

Comment: @AChampion I'm using 0.22.0. You are right. I can use it when I upgrade to 0.23.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can aggregate with `tuple` then convert to `list` with `applymap`

```
df.groupby(['class1', 'class2']).agg(tuple).applymap(list).reset_index()

   class1  class2     values    values2
0       1       0     [1, 3]     [5, 3]
1       1       1        [2]        [8]
2       2       0     [5, 2]     [6, 5]
3       2       1  [4, 2, 3]  [2, 3, 1]
4       3       0     [1, 3]     [3, 3]
5       3       1     [4, 2]     [2, 4]
```

Comment: Does `df.groupby(['class1', 'class2']).agg(list).reset_index()` not work for you?

Comment: Correct `Function does not reduce`.  Pandas wants the result of the aggregator to be a reduced form.  lists are determined to be not reduced, while `tuple` is.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using, because this returns exactly the same result for me (`0.23.0`).

Comment: Seems it was fixed here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/18354